# How to get the URI of expo-image-picker into an cached image of react-native-expo-image-cache (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, imagepicker, image-caching

I am getting the **URI** of the **imagePicker** (expo-image-picker @13.3.1), but I can not get the URI in the **cached image** (react-native-expo-image-cache @4.1.0).

Here is my code snipped for the imagePicker and the return statement:

```
class SignUpForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    image: Asset.fromModule(require("../../assets/avatar_default.png")).uri,
    key: 1,
    errorMessage: null
  }

  pickImage = async () => {
    const { granted } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
    if (!granted) {
      return;
    }
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      console.log(result.uri);

      this.setState({image: result.uri});
      this.setState({key: this.state.key + 1});
    }
  };

render() {
    const { navigation }  = this.props;
    return(... <ChachedAvatar 
                resizeMode="cover"
                transitionDuration={900}
                tint="dark"
                preview={Asset.fromModule(require("../../assets/avatar_default.png")).uri}
                uri={this.state.image}
                key={this.state.key}
            />
...
    )
  }
};
```

The URI **works** perfectly with the **default Image element** (`<Image source={{ uri: image }}>`).

The output of **console.log(result.uri)** (this URI **does not work**) is:

```
file:///Users/timokurtz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F3B4F1EA-A039-4D48-BDA2-4158D628F9A1/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C4C55A2-F1B8-4991-AEEC-1FA7545C68FE/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fcoresoil-0e17f581-c238-4031-b1f8-cfb662e245e1/ImagePicker/8EAE216A-BA81-434A-A4FA-D1472CAA731E.jpg
```

The output of **console.log(Asset.fromModule(require("../../assets/avatar_default.png")).uri)** (this **URI works**) is:

```
 http://192.168.178.20:19000/assets/assets/avatar_default.png?platform=ios&hash=ebb0aa5f6d1badea222fee12bb599a1e?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false
```